# Adaptive Threshold Assertion Error OpenCV Python

Tags: python, opencv

I am getting following error while using adaptive threshold in python opencv. I have successfully converted rgb image to grayscale but adaptive threshold still not working

Code :

```
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
thresh = cv2.adaptiveThreshold(gray, 255, cv2.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, cv2.THRESH_BINARY, 3, 1)
```

Error:

```
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) D:\Build\OpenCV\opencv-3.4.2\modules\imgproc\src\thresh.cpp:1524: error: (-215:Assertion failed) src.type() == (((0) & ((1 << 3) - 1)) + (((1)-1) << 3)) in function 'cv::adaptiveThreshold'
```

Comment: Please, provide a proper [mcve]. The current code sample is obviously not one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I can imagine is that your `img` and `gray` numpy arrays are not with dtype `np.uint8`. This can cause this error because I've run the script of yours with a valid image input: `img = np.zeros((100, 100, 3), dtype=np.uint8)` and it works completely fine.